# Predicting Next Location and thereby unify targeted recommendation focused on next best destination

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, prediction

I am new to ml and i have no idea how to approach this problem? During a contest a problem statement is given to me to create app or web app on this problem. Can anybody provide me source from where i can learn the techniques to solve this problem?